# Is Firebase cloud functions, do the terminologies 2gen and v2 refer to the same thing?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm checking out the Quotas and Limits for Firebase Functions on https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas
I see that the timeout for 2gen functions is up to 60min.

[image]

And I was wondering how can I convert my functions to 2gen.
Is this what the "Cloud Functions v2 public preview" is about?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta

[image]

Do the terminologies "2gen" and "v2" refer to the same thing?

Sadly, in the docs they never use both terminlogies in the same page, so even though it looks like it's the same thing, it's still not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they refer to the same thing. To convert your existing functions to gen 2, you just need to use the top level functions from the new SDK. For example:

```
const {onRequest} = require('firebase-functions/v2/https')

exports.myfunction = onRequest((req, res) => {})
```